# Tastypie - How to only authorize update a model through foreign keys?

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

A have a Location model that is foreign key in many models. don't want users to be able to create, edit or delete a Location directly (using the /api/v1/location/ endpoint), but i want them to be able to do is while creating an object that has Location as its foreign key. 
e.g.:

```
/api/v1/event/
{
    "name": "xxx",
    "location": {
       <new location>
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reasonable solution would be to have 2 separate resources for same model. One used as standalone resource and second as reference inside of event both with different authorization rules.

```
class LocationLimitedResource(ModelResource):
    # ...

    class Meta:
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
        queryset = Location.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'location_limited'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = LocationAuthorization()
        # ...


class LocationResource(LocationLimitedResource):
    class Meta(LocationLimitedResource.Meta):
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        resource_name = 'location'


class EventResource(ModelResource):
    location = fields.ForeignKey(LocationResource, 'location', full=True)

    class Meta:
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
        queryset = Event.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'event'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = EventAuthorization()

jobs_api = Api(api_name='v1')
jobs_api.register(LocationLimitedResource())
jobs_api.register(LocationResource())
jobs_api.register(EventResource())
```

The other way which I am less favour of because it's bit hacky is this:

```
class LocationAuthorization(Authorization):
    # [...]

    def create_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        return '/api/v1/event/' == bundle.request.path:

    # [...]


class LocationResource():
    # [...]

    class Meta:
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
        queryset = Location.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'location'
        authorization = LocationAuthorization()
        # [...]
```

It of course obligates you to hardcode the paths of the resource you like to allow/disallow the access. It's not natural for the architecture after a while you can forget about that rule. Also it's harder for documentation and self discovery of API.